# How can I duplicate the effect in Aptana Studio 3 where GIT is running in a toolwindow using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pinvoke, aptana

I have created a small app to try and accomplish this but I am missing something.

https://gist.github.com/852060

Basically when I run that code I get the GIT bash window as a sub window of the Form and I can move it around. I would like it to just fill the Form.

Can anyone recommend a way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole solution is not that simple as you may expect. Basically you want something line http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

If you don't need coloring, you could just pipe the process output to your text area.

Cheers,
Max

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this:

```
private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetWindowPos(
        processWindowHandle,
        HWND_TOP, 
        0, 
        0, 
        ClientRectangle.Width, 
        ClientRectangle.Height, 
        0
    );
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really work. It allows the window to resize but it still has its borders and the parent form loses focus when you select the command prompt window.

Comment: You'll have to modify the window style with a call to `SetWindowLong()` passing `WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN` as the style.